# IDistributedCache SQL Server delete expired records

Tags: asp.net-core, distributed-caching

I am using IDistributedCache with SQL Server in my ASP.Net Core 2.2 API.

I noticed that the expired records remain in the table. Is there any way to delete expired records from the cache table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SqlServerCache` periodically checks for deleted cache items and deletes them, it uses this SQL command.

```
DELETE FROM {0} WHERE @UtcNow > ExpiresAtTime
```

Please check you DB table for values of `ExpiresAtTime`.

Source of SqlServerCache class: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Caching/SqlServer/src/SqlServerCache.cs

Source of DatabaseOperations class, containing `DeleteExpiredCacheItems` method: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Caching/SqlServer/src/DatabaseOperations.cs

Comment: Links didn't work, therefore I updated your asnwer

Answer (score 1):

By default the `SqlServerCache` delete expired cache items every **30** minutes.

You can also configure it with `ExpiredItemsDeletionInterval` property of `SqlServerCacheOptions` in Program.cs (or Startup.cs) like as below:

```
builder.Services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    // Other settings can be here

    // This value cannot less than 5 minutes, for more information you can see constructor of SqlServerCache 
    options.ExpiredItemsDeletionInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
});
```

**Note**: `SqlServerCache` is not using **timer**, **scheduler** or etc. for delete expired items.
If deletion is required, `SqlServerCache` attempts to delete expired items, after each read or write operation.

The deleting code of `SqlServerCache` is below:

```
private void ScanForExpiredItemsIfRequired()
{
    lock (_mutex)
    {
        var utcNow = _systemClock.UtcNow;
        if ((utcNow - _lastExpirationScan) > _expiredItemsDeletionInterval)
        {
            _lastExpirationScan = utcNow;
            Task.Run(_deleteExpiredCachedItemsDelegate);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can see source code of [SqlServerCache](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Caching/SqlServer/src/SqlServerCache.cs), [DatabaseOperations](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Caching/SqlServer/src/DatabaseOperations.cs) and [SqlQueries](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Caching/SqlServer/src/SqlQueries.cs)